# How to control firefox from vb6

Tags: firefox, vb6

Is there a way to control from VB6 a Firefox instance?

There's a corporate application. This application has a form, I need to catch the Firefox Session, then execute a script in Javascript that injects a function that makes a Post to that session.

I could do it in IE, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it for FireFox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the firefox activex control http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can control Firefox (and other browsers) using a number of languages via Selenium.

Selenium is usually used for QA testing, but it sounds like it could be used in your scenario.

Selenium website: http://seleniumhq.org

One thing to note is that [the list of languages supported by Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages) does not include VB6. This is hardly surprising given that VB6 has been obsolete for over 10 years. It does say that "Any language that can make an HTTP call can pass commands to the Selenium Remote Control server.", but that means you'll probably have to write your own interface layer if you plan to stick with VB6.